# whats means "Link executables with xxx.lib"

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have one guide integrating software files to my program on c++. Steps are:

-Add /Resources/xxx-io/include/ directory to your project include directories settings

-Add /Resources/xxx-io/lib/ directory to your project library directories settings

-Include xxx.h in your software code

Link executables with xxx.lib

What dose the last one mean? I'm building simple win console program with visual studio 2015 c++ that communicates with software. I have linked the lib and includes and included header, but that last one is mystery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To say simply, it means that you should go to `Project properities -> Linker -> Input` and add there library, to which you want your executable to link to.

If you want to learn what does it actually mean, read some articles on how `.lib`s work. To say shortly, `.lib` library is compiled code, that is inserted into your program.